# Can a 12v 27a alkaline battery damage?

Tags: 12v, damage, alkaline

I've looked inside my garage remote control and I've discovered a 12v 27a battery. The voltage is very low, but the ampere are many, can it damage a person when is fully charged? Thanks

Comment: How big is this remote control?!

Comment: It's a normal remote..

Comment: A 27 Ampere 12 volt alkaline battery would do the most damage if you dropped it on someone...

Comment: No, it will not hurt anyone.

Answer (score 8):

That's a 27A-size battery, not a battery capable of providing 27 amperes of current. The maximum current from that battery can best be described as "piddly", which is all a remote control needs.